# How to add Smarty templating engine to CodeIgniters 3 framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

How do I add & use Smarty templating engine in CodeIgniters 3?

Note that CodeIgniters 3 does not have templating engine and you supposed to mix HTML code with PHP code & tags. Not to mention - you can't extend other views (like you do in Laravel or Smarty).

It's framework after all, not an additional hassle.

Answer (score 3):

### Installation & Configuration

1. Get your CodeIgniter folder up & running, so your welcome page is working.
2. Go to [Smarty download page](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/releases/) and download the latest "*Source code
   (zip)*".
3. Extract that Smarty ZIP folder and rename it to **smarty**.
4. Move **smarty** folder from #3 step to your CodeIgniters *application/third_party* folder. Like this - `your_project/application/third_party/smarty`.
5. Create new PHP file **SmartyLibrary.php** in your project's *application/libraries/* folder. Like this - `your_project/application/libraries/SmartyLibrary.php`.
6. In your created **SmartyLibrary.php** file, put the following contents and go straight to step **#7**.

   ```
   <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   require_once(APPPATH . 'third_party/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');

   class SmartyLibrary extends Smarty {

   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();

       // Define directories, used by Smarty:
       $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH . 'views');
       $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH . 'cache/smarty_templates_cache');
       $this->setCacheDir(APPPATH . 'cache/smarty_cache');
   }


   }
   ```
7. Analyse `__construct()` function, especially this part:

   ```
   // Define directories, used by Smarty:
   $this->setTemplateDir(APPPATH . 'views');
   $this->setCompileDir(APPPATH . 'cache/smarty_templates_cache');
   $this->setCacheDir(APPPATH . 'cache/smarty_cache');
   ```

These 3 lines are required for Smarty itself (it's part of [Smarty basic installation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl)). Ensure that these defined directories exist in your project (create them) and ensure they have correct permissions (smarty needs to create cache files).

8. Go to your project's `application/config/autoload.php` and edit like this:

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('SmartyLibrary' => 'smarty');
   ```

   Or if you don't want to load Smarty automatically - use this in your controllers:

   ```
   $this->load->library('SmartyLibrary', 'smarty');
   ```
9. That's it! Use smarty object like any other CodeIgniter library. Like this:

   ```
   $this->smarty->xxxxxxxxx('xxxxxxxxx', xxxxxxxx);
   ```

### Testing

1. Consider you use same Smarty directories as given above (file **SmartyLibrary.php**) - create new file `welcome.tpl` in your project's `application/views/` (like this: `application/views/welcome.tpl`) with the following contents:

   ```
   <html>
   <header><title>This is title</title></header>
   <body>
   {$message}
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Edit your default `Welcome.php` controller like this (assuming you auto-load smarty library):

   ```
   <?php
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

       public function index(){
           // Assign session data to Smarty:
           $this->smarty->assign('message', "This is Smarty test!");

           // Compile smarty template and load it to user:
           $this->smarty->display('welcome.tpl');
       }
   ```

   }
3. Try to load your project's base URL. You should see "This is Smarty test!" message on screen!.

### Final thoughts

- When defining location of CSS or JS files in Smarty views - use something like this - `{base_url()}css/bootstrap.min.css`.
- Things like this in CodeIgniter's views `<?php echo form_open('books/input'); ?>` can now be replaced in Smarty templates as `{form_open('books/input')}`.

Comment: Any mistakes? Any improvements? I tried to explain it as clearly as possible.

Comment: this should be on code review. you asked and answered your own question at the same time. very strange.

Comment: @Alex this would be off-topic on code review as it isn't a real implementation, additionally, self answers are also a thing on stack overflow....

Comment: i'm aware, but within seconds of posting? what is the point of even asking a question then? there are already similar questions here on stack one can add this answer to.

Comment: I am sharing my knowledge. Is it anything wrong for doing it?

Comment: you could have added your answer to any 1 of the questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=smarty+integration+codeigniter ... i just don't get why you asked a question to just immediately post an answer. further, there are already a plethora of libs on git that handle the integration. the one i personally use allows the integration with HMVC by wiredesignz, templating, and the usage of `$this` within the `.tpl` files and follows the same principles as the codeigniter view loader https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty

Comment: Totally agree with you.